# WCF TCP binding or Named pipes for grid computing?

Tags: .net, wcf, named-pipes, grid-computing

I'm building a distributed system. There are several applications (some are .Net based (C#), others are C++ based (NOT C++/CLI!)). 
Those apps will be installed on each computer in cluster (currently Windows-driven).
On local PC I use for IPC: MemoryMappedFiles for C# apps, Shared Memory for C++ apps, Named Pipes for IPC between C# and C++.
Over internet I use WCF TCP binding, using C# apps as bridges for C++ apps.

What would be better to use for LAN communication? MPICH2, it seems, use TCP...
Are typical named pipes quicker than WCF TCP binding with optimizations (disabled security, etc.)? The messages will be extremely large, mostly of double type. WCF is extremely convenient in my situation (all mathematical methods are simply contracts), but it's performance is a question.

Answer (score 0):

Read this, http://weblogs.asp.net/spano/archive/2007/10/02/choosing-the-right-wcf-binding.aspx.

You can see that the choice depends where the service is located. Hope it helps.

Comment: This can also be useful, http://wcfsecurity.codeplex.com/wikipage?title=Which%20bindings%20are%20best%20suited%20for%20the%20Intranet%3f&referringTitle=Questions%20and%20Answers

Answer (score 0):

You are mixing two different layers, you can run [WCF over NamedPipes](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.servicemodel.netnamedpipebinding.aspx) also. Named pipes (while can work with a lot of setup word) are not designed to communicate between two processes on two computers.

See this MSDN page on [Choosing a Transport](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms733769.aspx) to help you understand when to use what transport.

> **Advantages of Each Transport**
>
> This section describes the main reasons for choosing any one of the
>   three main transports, including a detailed decision chart for
>   choosing among them.
>
> **When to Use HTTP Transport**
>
> HTTP is a request/response protocol between clients and servers. The
>   most common application consists of Web-browser clients that
>   communicate with a Web server. The client sends a request to a server,
>   which listens for client request messages. When the server receives a
>   request, it returns a response, which contains the status of the
>   request. If successful, optional data, such as a Web page, an error
>   message, or other information is returned. For more information about
>   the HTTP protocol, see HTTP - Hypertext Transfer Protocol.
>
> The HTTP protocol is not connection-based—once the response is sent,
>   no state is maintained. To handle multiple-page transactions, the
>   application must persist any necessary state.
>
> In WCF, the HTTP transport binding is optimized for interoperability
>   with legacy non-WCF systems. If all communicating parties are using
>   WCF, the TCP-based or named pipes-based bindings are faster. For more
>   information, see NetTcpBinding and NetNamedPipeBinding.
>
> **When to Use the TCP Transport**
>
> TCP is a connection-based, stream-oriented delivery service with
>   end-to-end error detection and correction. Connection-based means that
>   a communication session between hosts is established before exchanging
>   data. A host is any device on a TCP/IP network identified by a logical
>   IP address.
>
> TCP provides reliable data delivery and ease of use. Specifically, TCP
>   notifies the sender of packet delivery, guarantees that packets are
>   delivered in the same order in which they are sent, retransmits lost
>   packets, and ensures that data packets are not duplicated. Note that
>   this reliable delivery applies between two TCP/IP nodes, and is not
>   the same thing as WS-ReliableMessaging, which applies between
>   endpoints, no matter how many intermediate nodes they may include.
>
> The WCF TCP transport is optimized for the scenario where both ends of
>   the communication are using WCF. This binding is the fastest WCF
>   binding for scenarios that involve communicating between different
>   machines. The message exchanges use the
>   BinaryMessageEncodingBindingElement for optimized message transfer.
>   TCP provides duplex communication and so can be used to implement
>   duplex contracts, even if the client is behind network address
>   translation (NAT).
>
> **When to Use the Named Pipe Transport**
>
> A named pipe is an object in the Windows operating system kernel, such
>   as a section of shared memory that processes can use for
>   communication. A named pipe has a name, and can be used for one-way or
>   duplex communication between processes on a single machine.
>
> When communication is required between different WCF applications on a
>   single computer, and you want to prevent any communication from
>   another machine, then use the named pipes transport. An additional
>   restriction is that processes running from Windows Remote Desktop may
>   be restricted to the same Windows Remote Desktop session unless they
>   have elevated privileges.